# Entire silver light screen in Light Switch

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to create a entire screen in silver light and use it in my light switch application.I find it very difficult to create custom page design as per client requirement in light switch..Can any one suggest me some ideas or point me to some useful links..Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see:
Help Desk: An Advanced Visual Studio LightSwitch Application
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/86/Help-Desk-An-Advanced-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-Application.aspx

Comment: does creating a silver light screen and adding it to Light switch affect its performance or will it affect any light switch functionality like converting an application to web and window based .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide on how to use Silverlight controls with lightswitch. http://dearmusings.wordpress.com/tag/custom-control/ I am using a scheduler control in the demo but it could be pretty much anything else that's Silverlight.